# how to make model in flutter to send nested map to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i am doing app that controlling esp32 via firebase .. i have 4 pumps that i have to set there parameters like

`

```
"pump1"{
'pump':1'
'dosingAmount':10 ,
'numberOfDoses':5,
'startTimeHour':10,
'startTimeMinute':10, 
'StopTimeM':10,
}

"pump2"{
'pump':2'
'dosingAmount':10 ,
'numberOfDoses':5,
'startTimeHour':10,
'startTimeMinute':10, 
'StopTimeM':10,
}

"pump3"{
'pump':3'
'dosingAmount':10 ,
'numberOfDoses':5,
'startTimeHour':10,
'startTimeMinute':10, 
'StopTimeM':10,
}

"pump4"{
'pump':4'
'dosingAmount':10 ,
'numberOfDoses':5,
'startTimeHour':10,
'startTimeMinute':10, 
'StopTimeM':10,
}
```

`

I have made realTimeDatabase referance like

```
late DatabaseReference realTimeDosingSetting =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("data");
```

and to send the data to firebase i used function like

```
void updateDosingSetting(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    realTimeDosingTimes = realTimeDosingTimes.child(
        '${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/realTimeDosingSetting');
    await realTimeDosingTimes
        .update(data)
        .then((_) => print("data sent sucussfully"))
        .catchError((error) => print("you got error $error"));
  }
```

and i have made 4 forms to collect the data for each pump to send to the database and with the use of one button i have used this

```
 IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    AuthController().updateDosingSetting({
                                      'pump1': {
                                        'dosingAmount': totalAmount1.text,
                                        'numberOfDoses': numberOfdoses1.text,
                                        'startTimeHour': startTime1.hour,
                                        'startTimeMinute': startTime1.minute,
                                        'stopTimeHour': stopTime1.hour,
                                        'stopTimeMinute': stopTime1.minute
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_circle_right,
                                    size: 70,
                                    color: AppConst.mainBlue,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

it works but i need to make the work easier like i need to make class of pump with those attributes but i do not know how to make this class give nested map as map my problem is do not know how make object with nested map and this object convert to nested map to use it to send the data ! i do not know if i can explain my question or not :( but how to model nested maps to use them in firebase realTimeDataBase ?

i tried to make nested map as object as give them to firebase funcion update() but error of only accept Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.